# Assign value to new List property (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have table  class Logging

Here is code:

```
public partial class Logging
{
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GPSDateTime2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Datatype { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

Also I have ViewModel

```
 public class HeatmapViewModel
{
    public decimal? Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public int FirstStartDifference { get; set; }
    public int LastStartDifference { get; set; }
    public int coeff = 2;
    public int Difference;
}
```

I have method in repository where I do all calculations

Here is code

```
var allitems = ctx.Loggings.AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new Logging
                {
                    Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                    Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                    CurDateTime = x.CurDateTime,
                    Datatype = x.Datatype

                });
            var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == 1 || x.Datatype == 2).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
            for (int i = 1; i < filteredQuery.Count; i++)
            {
                if (filteredQuery[i].Datatype == 2 && filteredQuery[i - 1].Datatype == 1)
                {
                    TimeSpan differenceTicks = filteredQuery[i].CurDateTime - filteredQuery[i - 1].CurDateTime;
                    var differenceInMinutes = (int) differenceTicks.TotalMinutes;

                }
            }

            items.Add(new HeatmapViewModel
            {
                Latitude2 = allitems.Longitude2,
                Longitude2 = allitems.Longitude2,
                Difference = differenceInMinutes
            });
```

I have trouble with this block of code:

```
  items.Add(new HeatmapViewModel
            {
                Latitude2 = allitems.Longitude2,
                Longitude2 = allitems.Longitude2,
                Difference = differenceInMinutes
            });
```

Here is errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude2' and no extension method 'Longitude2' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Repository\HeatmapRepository.cs 91  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude2' and no extension method 'Longitude2' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Repository\HeatmapRepository.cs 92  Active
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'differenceInMinutes' does not exist in the current context    Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Repository\HeatmapRepository.cs 93  Active

How I can solve them?

Comment: Why in the world do you have that first query - replace it with just `var allitems = ctx.Loggings;` And you need to add instance of `HeatmapViewModel` inside the `for` loop (assuming `items` is `List<HeatmapViewModel>`)

Comment: okay. about first query understood, my fault. But how I need to add instance of `HeatmapViewModel` in for? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Inside your `if` block - `items.Add(new HeatmapViewModel{ Latitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Latitude2, ...., Difference = differenceInMinutes});`

Comment: You do realize this will only generate a `HeatmapViewModel` for every 2nd item because of your `if` block (assuming the `Datatype` value alternates for each item in the query). Its hard to understand what you really wanting to do here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:  `allitems` is an `IEnumerable`, so you can't use `allitems.Longitude2` to get value of Longitude2. It's not a single item.

I think you should put `items.Add(...)` block to `for` loop.

And use `filteredQuery[i].Longitude2` instead of `allitems.Longitude2`.

Like this

```
       var filteredQuery = (
                            from log in ctx.Loggings
                            where log.Datatype == 1 || log.Datatype == 2
                            orderby log.Id descending
                            select log
                            ).ToList();

        var items = new List<HeatmapViewModel>();

        for (int i = 1; i < filteredQuery.Count; i++)
        {
            if (filteredQuery[i].Datatype == 2 && filteredQuery[i - 1].Datatype == 1)
            {
                TimeSpan differenceTicks = filteredQuery[i].CurDateTime - filteredQuery[i - 1].CurDateTime;

                items.Add(new HeatmapViewModel
                {
                    Latitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Longitude2,
                    Longitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Longitude2,
                    Difference = (int)differenceTicks.TotalMinutes
                });
            }
        }
```